# Como passar dados pesquisados por uma view de volta para a própria view

Tags: laravel, view, laravel-blade

Eu preciso pesquisar um banco de dados através de uma view (Laravel Blade).
Os dados obtidos, guardados num array, necessito exibir na própria página chamou o banco de dados.
Não estou obtendo êxito no retorno do array com tais dados, porque não sei como tratar o array dentro do bloco da view que espera esta resposta.

Explico:

A view que prepara a consulta ao banco de dados tem um formulário, com um botão Submit.
Esta ação dispara um método do Controller que vai ao banco de dados, pesquisa os dados e retorna um array.
Os dados existem, o array está populado.
São os seguintes passos:

Primeiro, a view e o formulário.
Nome do arquivo: listar.blade.php:

```
@extends ('PrincipalView')
@corpo
<form name="frmTSPesquisar" 
action="{{    action('TSController@pesquisarExecutar') }}" 
method="GET" role="form">
Busca: <input list="files" placeholder="20000">
<datalist id="files">
<option>20000</option>          
</datalist>         
<button type="submit">Pesquisar</button>
</form>
@stop
```

Veja que a tag Action do formulário já encaminha o que o Submit vai provocar.

Na página TSController.php, onde reside o método provocado, tenho o código:

```
public function pesquisarExecutar(Request $request) {
    $resultado=DB::table('tabts')
            ->join('tabfiles', 'tabts.file_tabfiles', '=', 'tabfiles.id')
            ->where('tabfiles.file',"=",$request->input('namSelNumFile'))
            ->get();

}//pesquisarExecutar
```

Neste método acima, como poderia fazer com que o array *$resultado* pudesse ser utilizado na mesma página (listar.blade.php) original, abaixo do formulário que provocou esta coleta de dados?

A estrutura deste aproveitamento do array *$resultado* poderia completar o código com o formulário de alguma maneira assim:

```
@extends ('PrincipalView')
@corpo
  <form name="frmTSPesquisar" 
action="{{  action('TSController@pesquisarExecutar') }}" method="GET" role="form">
    Busca: <input list="files" placeholder="20000">
    <datalist id="files">
    <option>20000</option>          
    </datalist>         
    <button type="submit">Pesquisar</button>
    </form>
@stop
{{-- abaixo seria o que eu preciso para interagir com a resposta via array --}}
@foreach ($resultado as $r)
{{r$->datalancamento}}
@endforeach
```

Enfim, meu problema está, acredito, em como passar o array para a view e, uma vez nesta view, como fazer um loop para aproveitar cada valor obtido dentro do array.

Comment: Você pode fazer com requisições via AJAX (js) .
Evitaria o "recarregamento" da páginas e formulário.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para passar variáveis para a view no laravel 5.* no retorno do método do seu controller utilize:

```
  return  view('listar',compact('resultado'));

    ou 

  return  view('listar',get_defined_vars());
```

Comment: Muito útil o seu comentário. Segui o que você disse e funcionou, mas mudei a passagem dos valores da seguinte forma: return view('listar')->with('resultado',$resultado);

Comment: Editei minha resposta porque quando você usa o compact a váriavel deve ser passada como string